# How to compile a program in Befunge-93?

Tags: befunge

How do I save and compile a program in Befunge-93? 
What file extension do I need to save the file as (like `fileName.what`)?
Then how do I compile it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Befunge is typically an interpreted language. In fact it was designed to be difficult to compile because the programs are self-modifying (but that hasn't stopped people from trying to write a compiler).

You should save the file however you like (a `.bf` extension is typically used) and run the interpreter (bef), passing the filename as a command line argument.

You can see the usage instructions in the [source code for the interpreter](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93/blob/814c47bbcf96425fe30f35acb5809f3a5a33de4c/src/bef.c#L40).

Comment: do i have an interpreter on my computer automatically though or do i have to download one? Where do i do this at?

Comment: @David: The reference implementation is found here: http://catseye.tc/projects/bef/. You download the source files and compile it using your favorite C compiler. There are some notes here: http://catseye.tc/about/prereqs.html#ansi_c

Comment: @David: And I hope you are aware that Befunge is an esoteric / joke language? ;-)

Comment: i am aware but i thought it might be fun to learn. I don't understnad how to use the intepreter. Is that source code you linked me to something i have to compile and run then? how do im compile it on my computer?

Comment: @David: Yes, you compile the source to get an executable called `bef`, or  `bef.exe` on Windows, and you can run that from the command line to execute your Befunge source.

Comment: how do i compile it though? i only know how to compile .java files with javac. im sort of new at this.

Comment: Nowadays there's good javascript implementations so that you can experiment with Befunge in your browser http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-playground#prog=hello,mode=edit

Answer (score 0):

As it is an interpreted language, it usually won't be compiled. A C# Befunge 93 interpreter below, that will read code as an array[] of strings.

```
string befunge93(string[] p) {
for (int i=0;i<p.Length;i++)
    p[i]=p[i].Replace("\"","ª"); // REMOVE QUOTATIONS TO MAKE THINGS EASIER
int l=0; int c=0; // current line and colum
var stack=new Stack<int>(new int[20000]); // initialize stack with many zeroes. 
string res=""; // output limited to 1000 chars
int limit=100000; // max commands limited to 10^5 
bool smode=false; // string mode
char direction='>';
//-------- MAIN LOOP ---------------
while (res.Length < 1000 && limit--> 0  )
    {
    var ch=p[l][c];
    if (ch=='ª') // ", TOGGLE STRING MODE
        smode = !smode;
    else if (smode) // STRING MODE => PUSH CHAR
        stack.Push((int)ch);
    else if (ch==',') // OUTPUT CHAR FROM STACK
        res+=(char)stack.Pop();
    else if (new Regex(@"[><^v]").IsMatch(""+ch)) // CHANGE DIRECTION
        direction = ch; 
    else if (new Regex(@"\d").IsMatch(""+ch)) // CHANGE DIRECTION
        stack.Push(ch-'0'); 
    else if (ch=='*') // MULTIPLICATION
        stack.Push(stack.Pop()*stack.Pop());
    else if (ch=='+') // SUM
        stack.Push(stack.Pop()+stack.Pop());
    else if (ch=='`') // GREATER THEN
         stack.Push(stack.Pop()>=stack.Pop()?0:1); 
    else if (ch=='!') // NOT
        stack.Push(stack.Pop()==0?1:0);
    else if (ch=='.') // OUTPUT NUMBER
        res+=$"{stack.Pop()} ";
    else if (ch=='#') // JUMP NEXT COMMAND
        move();
    else if (ch=='$') // DISCARD ITEM FROM STACK
        stack.Pop();
    else if (ch=='\\') // SWAP
        { var a=stack.Pop(); var b=stack.Pop(); stack.Push(a); stack.Push(b); }
    else if (ch=='%') // modulo
        { var a=stack.Pop(); var b=stack.Pop(); stack.Push(b%a); }
    else if (ch=='-') // MINUS
        { var a=stack.Pop(); var b=stack.Pop(); stack.Push(b-a); }
    else if (ch=='/') // DIVISION
        { var a=stack.Pop(); var b=stack.Pop(); stack.Push(b/a); }
    else if (ch==':') // DUPLICATE
        stack.Push(stack.First());
    else if (ch=='_' || ch=='|') // CONDITIONALS: MOVE IF STACK ZERO, LEFT OTHERWISE
        {
        var last = stack.Pop();
        if (ch=='_') direction=last==0?'>':'<'; // right if stack was zero. Left otherwise
        else direction=last==0?'v':'^'; // ch=='|'  
        }
    else if (ch==' '); // SPACE - DO NOTHING. 
    else return res;
    move();
    }
return res;
void move() // move cursor
{
    switch(direction)
        {
            case '>':
                if (++c==p[0].Length) c=0; break;
            case '<':
                if (--c==-1) c=p[0].Length-1; break;
            case 'v':
                if (++l==p.Length) l=0; break;
            case '^':
                if (--l==-1) l=p.Length-1; break;
            default: break;
        }
}
}
```